# Filter through elements and only select elements with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="page-content">
  <ul>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text 2 </li>
  </ul
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got the above HTML code as an example. I want to filter through each of the elements and only add a class to elements with text. I got some jQuery below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#page-content').find('*').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().trim().length){
      $(this).addClass('yay');
    }
  });
});
```

The code find each item in the page-content element and checks if it has text and add the class 'yay'. This does work, however it will give the parent element the class if its child has text in it. eg. It will give the `<ul>` the class because the `<li>` has text.

Is there something wrong with the code I am using or do I need to use a completely different script to only apply a class to elements with text?

**NOTE** The HTML is generated so I might end up with a `<ol>` instead of a `<ul>`, or a `<a>` tag contained inside #page-content.

Comment: Will yay be added to the all li tags and the h2 tag?

Comment: At the moment 'yay' gets added to every single element underneath 'page-content', but I just want it to be added to the 'li' and 'h2'. Look at my NOTE in the question. I am about to added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code to check if the element has any children, and add the class only if this is a text node. But if the HTML is not well formed this might cause problems.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#page-content').find('*').each(function() {
          if ($(this).children().length == 0 && $(this).text().trim().length) {
              $(this).addClass('yay');
          }
      });
  });
```